# Storing html source or contents of a variable in selenium ide?

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I am trying to build a macro in selenium ide that stores the page source to a file.  I see there is a command storeHtmlSource() that stores the page source to a variable, but I can't figure out how to store the contents of the variable to a file. Is there some direct way to do this or do I need to somehow have it execute javascript to do that?

I am totally new to selenium if that was not already obvious, but I have looked around the docs for a while and haven't figured it out.

Comment: Check this link you will have the answer to write to file http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11027122/how-to-load-write-data-into-a-newfile-using-selenium-ide

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately you can not do this with Selenium IDE. The IDE has not been designed to do things like this since there is Selenium Rc that allows you to do what the IDE can do and more since you use your favourite language to speak to a proxy and then use that language's ability to write things to the disk.

The IDE is designed to help you get the skeleton of a test case with the record function, you then tweak it, replay to see it works and then export to your favourite language

Comment: This is what I wound up doing. I had the ide generate perl and went from there.