# How to load/write data into a newfile using selenium IDE?

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I'm using selenium IDE to record & replay some testcase.
During this, i stored some values in variables.Now i've to load/write these variable's value into new file.How can i do it ? is it possible ?

Answer (score 5):

It's not possible using the Selenium IDE, but you can store using Selenium RC or Webdriver (Junit or Nunit).

Comment: It is now possible using @tomm answer.

Answer (score 5):

It is definitely possible. You just need to create some javascript function using mozilla (firefox) addons API https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons, save this function in selenium core extension file http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/08_user_extensions.jsp and add this extension into Selenium IDE.

Sample function to write text file:

```
    // ==================== File Writer ====================
Selenium.prototype.doWriteData = function(textToSave, location)
{   
    var data = textToSave;
    var file = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile);
    file.initWithPath(location);
    var foStream = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/network/file-output-stream;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIFileOutputStream);
    foStream.init(file, 0x02 | 0x08 | 0x20, 0666, 0);
    var converter = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/intl/converter-output-stream;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIConverterOutputStream);
    converter.init(foStream, "UTF-8", 0, 0);
    converter.writeString(data);
    converter.close();
}
```

Read is simple to do as well, just add another function, something like "doReadData" more info here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/File_I_O

To add this script to Selenium-IDE, follow this instructions:

> 1. Create your user extension and save it as user-extensions.js. While this name isn’t technically necessary, it’s good practice to keep
>      things consistent.
> 2. Open Firefox and open Selenium-IDE.
> 3. Click on Tools, Options
> 4. In Selenium Core Extensions click on Browse and find the user-extensions. js file. Click on OK.
> 5. Your user-extension will not yet be loaded, you must close and restart Selenium-IDE.
> 6. In your empty test, create a new command, your user-extension should now be an options in the Commands dropdown.

Comment: Is it possible to modify this function to concatenate instead of re-write the file every time the command runs? I have to write to the file several times during a script execution, and this command just stores the last run data ... I tried to understand the function but I'm too newbie to modify it :(

Comment: @sanjuro8998 in init method use use 0x02 | 0x10 instead of 0x02 | 0x08 | 0x20 (second parameter of init method)

Comment: thank you very much, it worked!!! One last question: is it possible to add line breaks? for example, I wrote: writeData, text\n, c:\file.txt ... and after that another command like this ... they concatenated without the \n, so I was wondering if it's possible to each run, the command writes strings in new lines, if it's not possible no problem, this function already saves my life :)

Comment: @sanjuro8998 try to add new line directly into code, something like converter.writeString(data\n); but I'am not sure if this helps

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if selenium IDE is sufficient to achieve what you are trying to do but if you can export the recorded test case to any language like java and then you can easily modify the exported code to write the variables you have stored to any file using the inbuilt capabilities of languages such as java.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use storeEval command,it evaluates java script snippets and refer the tips posted in http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1171273.

Let me know the result.
-Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible using selenium IDE, you need to use selenium webdriver where you can code language to do read/write operation to a file.

Answer (score 0):

here you can find the answer how to read variables from CSV file (you should arrach .js file in the selenium IDE options as extension and at that page is also example how to use it)

http://openselenium.com/?p=19

Comment: We ask that users not simply post links to solutions because the links might stop working. Could you edit your answer to include a summary of the steps/example at the linked article?

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'file logging' for this, try below plugin

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/file-logging-selenium-ide/

Steps:

1. Install Addon
2. Set Log Level to 'Info'
3. Navigate to 'Options -> FileLogging' in IDE and provide path (`D:\Users\jmatthew\Desktop\Selenium\Log1.csv`)
4. Use command `storeText | id=abcd.aa | value`
5. Use command `echo | ${value}`
6. Read the CSV file using `VLOOKUP` for matching results contain 'echo'

Comment: This addon has now been removed.